# ValueError: Expected input batch_size (31) to match target batch_size (128)

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, neural-network, pytorch-lightning

The error occured in the code for a Spiking Neural Network. I am using the neuromorphic-MNIST dataset which is a spiking version of the original MNIST dataset. As libraries I am using tonic (for the NMNIST dataset), norse (for neuromorphic computing), lightning and torch.
The training works fine, the error is thrown in the `_shared_eval_step` function while testing:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from norse.torch import LIFParameters, LIFState
from norse.torch.module.lif import LIFCell, LIFRecurrentCell
from typing import NamedTuple
from norse.torch import LICell, LIState
import tonic #handling of eventbased datasets
import torchvision #pytorch library for computer vision
import numpy as np
from torchmetrics.functional import accuracy

sensor_size = tonic.datasets.NMNIST.sensor_size  #.dataset: Tonic method to call different datasets 
frame_transform = tonic.transforms.ToFrame(sensor_size=sensor_size, time_window=10000) 
trainset = tonic.datasets.NMNIST(save_to="./data", train=True) 
testset = tonic.datasets.NMNIST(save_to="./data", transform=frame_transform, train=False)

BATCH_SIZE = 128
trainset.transform = frame_transform

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    trainset,
    num_workers = 2,  
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    collate_fn=tonic.collation.PadTensors(batch_first=False), 
    shuffle=True, # shuffle=True: data reshuffled at every epoch
)

test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    testset,
    num_workers = 2,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    collate_fn=tonic.collation.PadTensors(batch_first=False),
    shuffle=False,
)

# pass the input and output dimension, hidden layer, learning rate
class SNN(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(
        self,
        input_features,
        hidden_features,
        output_features,
        tau_syn_inv,
        tau_mem_inv,
        record=False,
        dt=1e-3,
    ):
        super(SNN, self).__init__()

        self.l0 = LIFRecurrentCell(
            input_features,
            hidden_features,
            p=LIFParameters(
                alpha=100,
                v_th=torch.as_tensor(0.3),
                tau_syn_inv=tau_syn_inv,
                tau_mem_inv=tau_mem_inv,
            ),
            dt=dt,
        )
        self.l1 = LIFRecurrentCell(
            hidden_features,
            hidden_features,
            p=LIFParameters(
                alpha=100,
                v_th=torch.as_tensor(0.3),
                tau_syn_inv=tau_syn_inv,
                tau_mem_inv=tau_mem_inv,
            ),
            dt=dt,
        )
        self.l2 = LIFRecurrentCell(
            hidden_features,
            hidden_features,
            p=LIFParameters(
                alpha=100,
                v_th=torch.as_tensor(0.3),
                tau_syn_inv=tau_syn_inv,
                tau_mem_inv=tau_mem_inv,
            ),
            dt=dt,
        )
        # set bias=True, bias term accounts for difference in input and output dimensions
        self.fc0 = nn.Linear(hidden_features, hidden_features, bias=True) # fully connected
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(hidden_features, hidden_features, bias=False) # fully connected
        self.fc_out = nn.Linear(hidden_features, output_features, bias=False)
        self.out = LICell(dt=dt)

        self.input_features = input_features
        self.hidden_features = hidden_features
        self.output_features = output_features

    # forward pass
    def forward(self, x): 
        seq_length, batch_size, _, _, _ = x.shape
        
        voltages = []
        for ts in range(seq_length):
            z = x[ts, :, :, :].view(-1, self.input_features)  

            z = z.requires_grad_(True)
            z_clone = z.clone()  # Create a clone of z
            z, _ = self.l0(z_clone)
            z = self.fc0(z)
            
            z_clone = z.clone()  # Create a clone of z
            z, _ = self.l1(z_clone)
            z = self.fc1(z)
            z_clone = z.clone()  # Create a clone of z
            z, _ = self.l2(z_clone)            
            vo, readout_state = self.out(z)

            voltages.append(vo)

        return torch.stack(voltages) 

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=0.001)
        return optimizer

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_index):
        x, y = batch
        # Input has shape (32, 1, 34, 34): (batch, channel, x, y)
        out = self.forward(x)  # Forward pass to get the output
        out = out.mean(dim=0)  # Average across the time dimension
        loss = torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(out, y)
        return loss

    @torch.inference_mode()
    def test_epoch_end(self, outputs):
        avg_loss = torch.stack([x["test_loss"] for x in outputs]).mean()
        avg_accuracy = torch.stack([x["test_accuracy"] for x in outputs]).mean()
        return {"avg_test_loss": avg_loss, "avg_test_accuracy": avg_accuracy}

    @torch.inference_mode()
    def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        loss, acc = self._shared_eval_step(batch, batch_idx)
        metrics = {"test_acc": acc, "test_loss": loss}
        self.log_dict(metrics)
        return metrics

    @torch.inference_mode()
    def _shared_eval_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, y = batch
        y_hat = self(x)
        loss = torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(y_hat, y)
        acc = accuracy(y_hat, y)
        return loss, acc

LR = 0.002 
INPUT_FEATURES = np.product(trainset.sensor_size)
HIDDEN_FEATURES = 100
OUTPUT_FEATURES = len(trainset.classes)

model = SNN(input_features=INPUT_FEATURES,
        hidden_features=HIDDEN_FEATURES,
        output_features=OUTPUT_FEATURES,
        tau_syn_inv=torch.tensor(1 / 1e-2),
        tau_mem_inv=torch.tensor(1 / 1e-2),
        ) 

trainer = pl.Trainer(gpus=1, max_epochs=1)  
trainer.fit(model, train_loader)

trainer.test(model, dataloaders=test_loader)
```

I used the debugger to find out the shapes of x, y and y_hat:

```
x.shape
torch.Size([31, 128, 2, 34, 34])

y.shape
torch.Size([128])

y_hat.shape
torch.Size([31, 128, 100])
```

I then used `y_hat = y_hat.view(128, -1)` to resize the tensor, this throws this error:

```
RuntimeError: shape '[128, -1]' is invalid for input of size 49600
```

So I changed that back again.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I think you should also average across the time dimension in the _shared_eval_step function. Before calling the cross entropy, you should add in the function _shared_eval_step the line:

```
y_hat = y_hat.mean(dim=0)
```